# How to replace an AJAX post with Coldfusion within a cfc

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have been trying to find a way to do something that seems to be pretty simple but can't seem to find a solution out there. I have a post that is made with some HTML in it and would like to dynamically change portions of it. I am using Coldfusion 9 for server side, AJAX, and jQuery UI 1.10.1 & jQuery 1.9.1.

What I would like to do is post in AJAX and replace the data server side within the cfc. Here is the code I have on the Client side.

```
var ipost = '<li> <h2><a href="PersonsID" target="_blank">Persons Name</a></h2> </li>';
var message_a = $('#message_a').attr('value');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "cfc/cfc_Forum.cfc?method=func_AddNew&returnformat=json",
                    data: { message:"message_a=" + wall_post },
                    success: function () {
                        $('ul#posts').prepend(ipost);

                    }
                });
```

I would like to replace the "PersonsID" with a "Session.Variable1" and "Persons Name" with "Session.Variable2". The cfc would be standard protocol for CF. Here is what the component would look like.

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="func_AddNew" access="remote" returntype="struct">
    <cfargument name="message" type="string" required="true" />
        <--- ********** replace "Persons ID" and "Persons Name" ************** --->

        <!--- ********* INSERT INTO DATA BASE ************ --->

        <cfreturn return />
    </cffunction>   

</cfcomponent>
```

Any recommendations would be great!

Comment: currently, the value of the `data` property is invalid, it needs both a key and a value, not just a value. `data: { thestring: ipost }` Other than that, you'd just need to fill in the coldfusion component to do your replace/insert and make it return json `returntype="json"`

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I actually simplified my ajax code and didn't correctly simplify it for the sake of the example... :). My question really is related to the code within the cfc. I am struggling with how to go about replacing the "#arguments.message#". Sorry for the lack of clarity in my question.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to get the values with javascript instead? with javascript it would be as simple as `$(ipost).find("a").attr("href")` to get the id, and `.text()` to get the name.

Comment: Well.. if I could find a way to populate that with a server side Session variable, then it would be done that way. I am much more familiar with CF than JS so that may be why I am leaning to the server side replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will work but it does expose the person's personID if they were to look at the source code so there is a bit of a risk doing this.  The other thing you could do is pass the cftolken and try to find the correct variables in the cfc which takes a bit more effort.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "cfc/cfc_Forum.cfc?method=func_AddNew&returnformat=json",
    data: { message:"message_a=" + wall_post
          , personID: <cfoutput>#Session.Variable1#</cfoutput>
          , personName: <cfoutput>#Session.Variable2#</cfoutput>
            },
    success: function () {
         $('ul#posts').prepend(ipost);
                        }
                });
```

Comment: I think that will work! IDs are not a big issue. Thanks a bunch!